# 1px White Line between Border and Div when zooming in

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why, but when zooming the browser a 1px white line appears to the right and top of my div (right before the border). You can see the issue below:

[White Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1snFM.png)

The web page URL can be found here:

https://qa.modulos.ai/pricing/

As mentioned, this only occurs when zooming in/out, any ideas?

Thanks, Greg.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To remove the space at the top you have to remove the following style ``.elementor-column{ min-height: 1px; }``

Comment: I was able to see the bug only in Chrome. FF displays is without the white borders. I would suggest a visual trick. To the "div.elementor-column-wrap.elementor-element-populated" add a style "background-color: #6c757d;"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In my case the problem was: `box-sizing: border-box`